# setState only catches the last given value

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, state, setstate

why is the state only updated in the last if en else statement.
only the age in `setFilledIn` is set to `true` and `false`

Can someone help me to understand state in React?
because I don't know what I am doing wrong.

by the way, if I comment out the last if statement then the if statement for lastName works.

```
const [filledIn, setFilledIn] = useState({
firstName: true,
lastName: true,
age: true,
});

const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
event.preventDefault();
if (firstNameRef.current == null || firstNameRef.current.value === "") {
  setFilledIn({ ...filledIn, firstName: false });
} else {
  setFilledIn({ ...filledIn, firstName: true });
  person2.firstName = firstNameRef.current.value;
}
if (lastNameRef.current == null || lastNameRef.current.value == "") {
  setFilledIn({ ...filledIn, lastName: false });
} else {
  setFilledIn({ ...filledIn, lastName: true });
  person2.lastName = lastNameRef.current.value;
}

 if (ageRef.current == null || ageRef.current.value == "") {
   setFilledIn({ ...filledIn, age: false });
 } else {
   setFilledIn({ ...filledIn, age: true });
   person2.age = parseInt(ageRef.current.value);
 }

};
```

Comment: If you are setting multiple setState (setFilledIn) in your case then React will batch it and update it once.

Comment: latter value get replaced with the previous state if there is multiple state updates.

Answer (score 1):

`filledIn` won't change untill the component rerenders, and here each update to the state the code makes won't rerender the component, **it will only do when all the code isinde `handleSubmit` finishes executing**. therefore, since we are still in the same render, even when you update `firstName` of `filledIn` and then try to update `lastName` this way:

```js
setFilledIn({ ...filledIn, lastName: false });
```

`filledIn` still holds the same value without any update.
 however there is a way:

```
setFilledIn((prev) => {
  return {
    ...prev,
    lastName: false,
  };
});
```

with `prev` you can get access to the last value the state got even when the component didn't rerendered yet, then what you return is the value you want the state to be updated with.

this is actually the best way to update the state, you want it to always be updated based on its previous value and not based on its value during the current render, and what you run into is a good example of how this is better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're updating the state separately for each field, so only the last field's update will be reflected in the final state. This is because the setFilledIn function calls are asynchronous, and each call overwrites the previous update.

To fix this, you can update the state once at the end of the function, after checking all the fields.

```
const [filledIn, setFilledIn] = useState({
  firstName: true,
  lastName: true,
  age: true,
});

const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let updatedFilledIn = { ...filledIn };

  if (firstNameRef.current == null || firstNameRef.current.value === "") {
    updatedFilledIn.firstName = false;
  } else {
    updatedFilledIn.firstName = true;
  }

  if (lastNameRef.current == null || lastNameRef.current.value === "") {
    updatedFilledIn.lastName = false;
  } else {
    updatedFilledIn.lastName = true;
  }

  if (ageRef.current == null || ageRef.current.value === "") {
    updatedFilledIn.age = false;
  } else {
    updatedFilledIn.age = true;
  }

  setFilledIn(updatedFilledIn);
};
```

or you can simplify it to

```
const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let updatedFilledIn = { ...filledIn };

  const fields = {
    firstName: firstNameRef,
    lastName: lastNameRef,
    age: ageRef,
  };

  Object.entries(fields).forEach(([fieldName, fieldRef]) => {
    if (fieldRef.current == null || fieldRef.current.value === "") {
      updatedFilledIn[fieldName] = false;
    } else {
      updatedFilledIn[fieldName] = true;
    }
  });

  setFilledIn(updatedFilledIn);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, so it only qualifies as an educated guess. But I'm going to assume it has something to do with your user of the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) utility (the ...) each time you call setState. Technically you shouldn't need these since you've already initialized the state with useState. But if you want to use them instead of initializing the state then you'll have to put [] around your namespace in the keypair. For example:

```
setFilledIn({ ...filledIn, [lastName]: false });
```

or

```
setFilledIn({ lastName: false });
```

Hope this helps! [Here is a good explanation of setState and useState hooks.](https://dev.to/johnstonlogan/react-hooks-barney-style-1hk7)